# How to set a firefox profile on a Selenium WebDriver remote with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I want to set a Firefox profile to the following driver:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox
```

I've tried adding:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.downloadDir'] = '/home/seluser'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox, :profile => profile
```

But the profile option does not exist

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try as below :-

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.downloadDir'] = '/home/seluser'

capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => profile)

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => capabilities
```

**Note** :- You should follow [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) to learn more about `Ruby` binding.

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: would you know how to enable the flash plugin for a chrome profile at all please ?